# Html hover change list style images

Tags: html, html-lists

It is possible with html change `list-style-image:` in `hover` or `active` ?
Please example.

Comment: -1 for the very poor question, the answer can be both yes or no.

Comment: yes but you'll need css or some javascript/jquery, it can't be done purely with html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use CSS not HTML to achieve this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
</ul>`
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    list-style-image: url('original.png');
}

li:hover {
    list-style-image: url('replacement.png');
}
```